# certutil dump - expiration date p12 - powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate

I am not really a programmer but I am trying to get fixed a Powershell script that would help me get the expiration date from a P12 certificate on file.

This is the command:

```
   C:\>certutil.exe -dump c:\1\p_CERT.p12
Certificates: Not Encrypted
================ Certificate 0 ================
================ Begin Nesting Level 1 ================
Element 0:
Serial Number: 03g3
Issuer: CN=COMPANY MY  CA v2, O=Company SL, C=GL
 NotBefore: 2012-06-20 11:47
 NotAfter: 2022-06-20 11:46
Subject: CN=COMPANY MY CA v2, O=Company SL, C=GL
Signature matches Public Key
Root Certificate: Subject matches Issuer
Cert Hash(sha1): 1234124214214214214sdada122
----------------  End Nesting Level 1  ----------------
No key provider information
Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption.

================ Certificate 1 ================
================ Begin Nesting Level 1 ================
Element 1:
Serial Number: 2100
Issuer: CN=COMPANY MY CA v2, O=Company SL, C=GL
 NotBefore: 2018-12-07 08:48
 NotAfter: 2020-12-07 08:48             
Subject: CN=private_CERT + SERIALNUMBER=445566778899, O=OTHER_Company, C=GL
Non-root Certificate
Cert Hash(sha1): 1234423hhhshshhshsh444423232
----------------  End Nesting Level 1  ----------------
  Key Container = PfxContainer
  Provider = PfxProvider
Encryption test FAILED
CertUtil: -dump command completed successfully.
```

The interesting part is the second one, that with the SERIALNUMBER, the "NotAfter: 2020-12-07 08:48"

Using this one as a source of inspiration (https://gist.github.com/banterCZ/9bd6aa1ab49995fdf018), thanks banterCZ, I tried the following. But it is not working as the result is not the field "NotAfter".
Any thoughts how to get this part out "NotAfter: 2020-12-07 08:48" with the script?

```
########################################################
#
#       Check certificates inside a p12 certificate file
#
########################################################

[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$location,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [int]$threshold
)

[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = "en-US"

$certutil="certutil.exe"
$certificate = Invoke-Expression "$certutil -dump '$location'"

foreach($line in $certificate){    
    if($line.Contains("Element 1:")){    
        $index = $line.Substring(0,20)
        write-host $index
        $dateAsString = $line | Select-String -Pattern 'NotAfter' | foreach {$_.groups[""].value}
        write-host $dateAsString
        #$expirationDate = [datetime]::parseexact($dateAsString,"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy",$null)
        break
    }
}

$now = ([System.DateTime]::Now)
$daysToExpire = [int]($expirationDate - $now).TotalDays

if ($threshold -lt $daysToExpire) {
    Write-Host "[OK] Certificate '$alias' expires in '$expirationDate' ($daysToExpire day(s) remaining)."
    exit 0
} elseif ($daysToExpire -lt 0) {
    Write-Host "[CRITICAL] Certificate $alias has already expired."
    exit 2
} else {
    Write-Host "[WARNING] Certificate '$alias' expires in '$expirationDate' ($daysToExpire day(s) remaining)."
    exit 1
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Try using the Get-PfxData cmdlet instead

Comment: When i run the Get-PfxData i get this response below. Most likely this Get-PfxData will want the password of the certificate which i would preferably avoid attach to the script if the certutil dumps exactly the info i am after
`OtherCertificates
-----------------
{[Subject]...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a good buddy, J.I. is this script fixed.
I hope it helps someone else out there.

It looks for the line with the SERIALNUMBER, saves 1 line behind to a variable and so on.

```
########################################################
#
#       Check certificates inside a p12 file
#       J.I., banterCZ, trustbyte & stackoverflow
#
########################################################

[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$location,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$certserial,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [int]$warning,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [int]$critical

)

[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = "en-US"

$certutil="certutil.exe"
$certificate = $(Invoke-Expression "$certutil -dump '$location'")


$row = [array]::IndexOf($certificate,$certificate -match "$certserial")
$notbefore = $certificate[$row-1]
$notbefore = $notbefore.ToString().Replace(" NotAfter: ","")
$now = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")

$date1 = get-date $notbefore
$date2 = get-date $now
$daysToExpire = [int]($date1-$date2).TotalDays


if ($daysToExpire -lt $critical) {
    Write-Host "[CRITICAL] Certificate '$location' expires in '$notbefore' ($daysToExpire day(s) remaining)."
    exit 2
} elseif ($daysToExpire -lt $warning) {
    Write-Host "[WARNING] Certificate '$location' expires in '$notbefore' ($daysToExpire day(s) remaining)."
    exit 1
} else {
    Write-Host "[OK] Certificate '$location' expires in '$notbefore' ($daysToExpire day(s) remaining)"
    exit 0
}
```